# Как сделать программу которая повторит введенный тест с новой строки трижды

Tags: python

Пример:

Ввод: 2 + 2 = 4
Вывод: 2 + 2 = 4 2 + 2 = 4 2 + 2 = 4,

но вывод должен быть  с новой строки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите, как вы делали, что получилось в одну строку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так:

```
text = input("Введите, что хотите повторить: ")

print(text, text, text)                          # в одной строке
```

или

```
text = input("Введите, что хотите повторить: ")

print(text)                                      # в отдельных строках
print(text)
print(text)
```

Comment: Спасибо за советы. правильным ответом стало:
a = (input())
print(a, sep=""), print(a, sep=""), print(a, sep="")

Comment: @Святой, а зачем вы сепараторам присваиваете пустую строку?

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но с помощью этого действия я добился того, чтобы ответ расположился столбиком, а не строкой

Comment: @Святой, да, вы ошибаетесь. Когда вы не используете `,sep=""`, ничего не изменится. Между прочим, вы получите то же самое, что и в моем (вами неоцененном) ответе.

Answer (score 1):

> Как сделать программу которая повторит введенный тест с новой строки
> трижды

Вопрос = ответ

```
print((input() + " ") * 3)
```

Comment: Ваш код делает всё как у автора и было а не так как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, можно так:

```py
print((input() + '\n') * 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inputString = input()
i = 3 ##нужное кол-во раз
number = 0
outputString = str()
while number < i:
    outputString = outputString + " " + inputString
    number = number + 1
    
print(outputString.strip())
```

Comment: Имена переменных в джавовском стиле. Лучше так: `input_string`.

Comment: @Глеб после 7 месяцев кодинга на джаве это так заметно?))

Comment: Ну да) Программы на джаве очень характерны и одним из главных признаков бывшего джава-программиста является именно camelcase в именах переменных)